# Python: Saving / loading large array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, load

I have saved a large array of complex numbers using python,

```
numpy.save(file_name, eval(variable_name))
```

that worked without any trouble. However, loading,

```
variable_name=numpy.load(file_name)
```

yields the following error,

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Using: Python 2.7.9 64-bit and the file is 1.19 GB large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the size of your array, you likely didn't opened your file in the right way, try this:

```py
with open(file_name, "rb") as file_:
    variable_name = np.load(file_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle

# Saving:
data_file = open('filename.bi', 'w')
pickle.dump(your_data, data_file)
data_file.close()

# Loading:
data_file = open('filename.bi')
data = pickle.load(data_file)
data_file.close()
```

Comment: This has a significant overhead for numpy arrays. Using `numpy.save` or hdf5 file format is to be preferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, pickle / dump gave me a memory error for the big array. I'll try the upper version in an hour.

Comment: It is weird: On friday I ran the code repeatly without any error (even after closing the console)

today, i got the code repeatedly, even after restarting python/spyder. (The data was stored on a local drive)

Now, i re-ran the script and I can't reproduce the error. 

Once the error happens again, I will get back here .